# Python string variable

Tags: python

```
V=str(input ('\n\tEnter\n\n\t'))
if V.isnumeric:
    print (f'\n\tYour V is a numeric and it is "{V}"\n\t')
```

When I enter an alphabet, it  considers it as a numeric. How to make it only accept numbers or alphabets?

Comment: The return value of `input` is a string. There's no need to convert it to a string again.

Answer (score 5):

`isnumeric` is a function but you are not calling it so it is returning true as it is a defined function. Your `if` statement is checking whether `isnumeric` is defined for the variable `V`

You should do this -

```
V=str(input ('\n\tEnter\n\n\t'))
if V.isnumeric():
    print (f'\n\tYour V is a numeric and it is "{V}"\n\t')
```

Comment: It doesn't "return true". A function is truthy, which is not the same as "returning true". Returning is what happens when a function is called and `return`s a value.

Comment: Kind of annoying that the code does something unexpected with a simple typo, rather than generating an error, isn't it?

Comment: That's not a typo - that's an intended feature. If an object O has a member field `x`, it's referenced as `O.x` without the parens. Passing functions is valid, so this isn't really a typo - it's directly indicating a different evaluation.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, but it is not supposed to raise an error as it is valid python and sometimes you may want to check if the function is there on instance of a variable.

Comment: @NathanielFord it's obviously a typo when you consider the desired result.

Comment: @MarkRansom *shrug* I suppose. But all functions are *called* with parens, so it's hard to expect a function to be called if you don't include those. I'm not sure how an error *would* be thrown in this situation.

Comment: @Pythony I'm not arguing against the way Python does things, I actually think it provides a lot of flexibility and is a net positive.  I wouldn't change a thing.

Comment: @NathanielFord I recognize that it is valid Python and I appreciate the capabilities it affords.  I also agree that it would be nearly impossible for Python to detect your intent and generate an error.  I just think it's unfortunate that such an easy to make typo isn't caught earlier in the process.  This certainly isn't the first StackOverflow question I've seen caused by missing parentheses.

Comment: @MarkRansom This is no doubt the sort of thing ML-backed autocompletion ought to be able to help with in the not too distant future.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `V.isnumeric()` there is some limitations on negative

```
Definition and Usage
The isnumeric() method returns True if all the characters are numeric (0-9), otherwise False.

Exponents, like ² and ¾ are also considered to be numeric values.

"-1" and "1.5" are NOT considered numeric values, because all the characters in the string must be numeric, and the - and the . are not.
```

This should be useful if you want to try a couple of functions: https://lerner.co.il/2019/02/17/pythons-str-isdigit-vs-str-isnumeric/

Answer (score 1):

The function [`isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) is not being called in your code presently, you are simply referencing it:

```
if v.isnumeric:  # This resolves to a pointer to the isnumeric function
    ....
```

To call a function, you require `v.isnumeric()`. Note that in the original (without parentheses) it resolves to function object, which in turn evaluates to `True` (essentially, because it exists at all) when in an `if` clause. However, the function itself is never run. It's for this reason that you're seeing it print out every time.